# Android: App not runnin on Nexus 10 with Jellybean - works fine on older devices

Tags: android, api, backwards-compatibility, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My app targets version 2.2 and seems to run fine on the 3 devices I've tested it on (version 2.2 and 2.3)

However, I just ran it on a Google Nexus 10 tablet and the splash screen works OK and takes a touch input to start the next activity (a menu system based off of SurfaceView using multiple threads) and although it displays / animates OK, none of the buttons are working - I'm not really sure where to begin, am I wrong in assuming apps written for older Android API's are not compatible with newer releases of the OS? Surely newer versions are backwardly compatible?

Thanks all!!

Edit: If I repeatedly hit the start button, Logcat is showing this:

[image]

So not sure why this is doing this on JB but OK on devices running older OS's - thank you all.

Edit 2:

Code for 'button' release (after 'button' press):

```
if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){      

Intent StartNewGame = new Intent((Activity) getContext(), StartGame.class);     

    getContext().startActivity(StartGame);  

// Oddly, if I put a System.exit(0); here, game activity starts and everything is fine - obviously this is only for testing and needs to be removed.

return true;}

    }
```

Comment: try setting your android build to 4.1

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, unfortunately, this hasn't worked -it doesn't seem to crash any more, but the game still isn't starting when the start button is pressed. Should my 'target API' not be set to the actual lowest version that I'm targeting? I just changed it back to 2.2 and it's not crashing still, but not starting either still :-( Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: You can target to higher versions without having any problems on your  codes, but there are deprecated methods (doesn't give any errors, but it's recommended to change it). What is happening when you push the start button? Did you try to add a log to your button?

Comment: Thanks, so what is the usual method?  I've always had my target API level set to the lowest API I want to target - my understanding is that if I then try to use an API that is not available Eclipse will flag it, if I set my API to the latest version, if I use an API that is unavailable in an earlier version, Eclipse will flag it for me - just kind of a fail-safe!!  When press the button my game activity isn't starting pretty much nothing happen!! :-(  I have put a log in so I can see in DDMS that the button press is being registered!! Thanks again for all your help :-)

Comment: I didn't mean about the api target on the manifest.xml, you can change your android build to higher level by right clicking your project > Properties > Android > Check Android 4.1 > Apply. and can you edit your post and add your code on your button?

Comment: Interesting, I've just actually notices something - I'm putting my thread - ending code into surfaceDestroyed, but that method isn't actually being called when I start my next activity - I was under the impression it was supposed to be destroyed when exiting and starting another activity?  I think this is what is causing the problem.  If I move my thread-ending code to within the button release code, the game appears to start OK with no problems, so I guess my question should be where should I put the code that ends my thread?  Should have it in both places?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        if ((n & -n) == n) {
            return (int) ((n * (long) next(31)) >> 31);
        }
        int bits, val;
        do {
            bits = next(31);
            val = bits % n;
        } while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0);
        return val;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

That is the code from the source for 4.1 so it looks like you are some how passing a 0 to the function , is there any way this could happen in your code?

Comment: Hmmmmm - thanks for this, I will check my code to see it is possible that this could be happening - maybe JB deals with Randoms differently than 2.x?!  Strange if this is the case.... Thanks!!

Comment: Hey just to let you know strangely, I don't think it's anything to do with the actual random number routine, I think that's a red herring, it seems to be to do with the "event.getAction()" part of the code - JB doesn't seem to like this! It's only when I touch the screen that I start to get problems - any ideas?! Thanks

Comment: That is weird, since your stack trace clearing shows a IllegalArgumentException being thrown. 

Maybe a try block in your code and also log the inputs to your nextInt() calls.

Comment: Hi, please see my comment on the above posters response - I think this is what is causing my problem - any idea where I am 'supposed' to put the code that ends my thread - obviously my thread wasn't ending so that was (I believe), causing my problems - any suggestions welcome thank you.